# internationalized database - possible in one sqlite db?

Tags: database, sqlite, localization

we're working out a concept for a database containing entries in different languages. let's say like this:

entry 1 in english
entry 2 in chinese 
entry 3 in spanish
entry 4 in english
entry 5 in hindi
entry 6 in english
...

Is it possible to collect all entries in one database? or does it require one database per localization/typo setting?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this in one database, make sure you use UTF-8.

We do this in several iPhone apps with up to 20 languages sharing one Core Data (backed by SQLite) database.

Comment: Thank you. How far does that go? We'd need to mix up entirely different character sets when displaying the data on the screen. From what I get: new entries have to send their language information and get decoded to UTF-8 to fit into the database. From there every entry can be picked up with the language information, encoded and therefore visualized properly with the respective character set. Is that right? And can  objects like "text field" or the tables allow detailed configurations regarding this? Means table cell 7 to be set to arabian characters, table cell 13 to latin etc.?

Comment: What language is your client app actually being written in?  The database is happy as long as everything is sent in in UTF-8, it will happily store it, and then send it back un-mangled, the key is whether the client language is as friendly.

Comment: the plan is having about 10-15 languages (while english is default, it goes along russian, arabic, chinese, japanese, etc.) available to choose from. addressing the app globally is essential and it's okay when it requires special treatment for sets which are not utf-8 compatible.